# How to convert binary to decimal i a have code for up to 2 power 10 i need help to 2 power 32

Tags: java, arrays

How to convert **binary** to **decimal** i a have code for up to **2 power 10** i need help to **2 power 32**

I have tried some other website for the program where i can change to get the appropriate answerer for my coding

```
{
    int [] positionNumsArr= {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};//for up to 2 power 8 binary value
    int[] numberSplit = new int [8];
    Scanner scanNum = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count1=0;
    int decimalValue=0;


    System.out.println("Please enter a positive binary number.(Only 1s and 0s)");
    int number = scanNum.nextInt();

    while (number > 0) 
    {     
        numberSplit[count1]=( number % 10);
        if(numberSplit[count1]!=1 && numberSplit[count1] !=0)
        {
        System.out.println("Was not made of only \"1\" or \"0\" The program will now restart");
        main(null);
        }
        count1++; 
        number = number / 10;
    }

    for(int count2 = 0;count2<8;count2++)
    {
        if(numberSplit[count2]==1)
        {
            decimalValue=decimalValue+positionNumsArr[count2];
        }
    }

    System.out.print(decimalValue);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `Long.parseLong()` and specify `2` as the base. Example:

```
String str = "11101000101";
Long num = Long.parseLong(str, 2); // parse it in base 2, i.e., binary
System.out.print(num); // outputs 1861
```

This will work up to 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (the max Long value).

[Here's a working demo](http://ideone.com/N7JnwR).

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah, crud. I saw the JavaScript tag and assumed (oops) OP knew what he or she was doing... Sigh...